# multi elements styling in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visual-studio-code

Not long ago I made a small library using jQuery for spacing (margin and padding).

Now I'm trying to switch this library to pure Javascript with your help :)

Here's my js code:

```js
// Useful Vars
let dataAttr = "[data-m], [data-mt], [data-mr], [data-mb], [data-ml], [data-my], [data-mx], [data-p], [data-pt], [data-pr], [data-pb], [data-pl], [data-py], [data-px]";
let dataSpacing = $("[data-spacing]").find(dataAttr);
let p = "px";

// Margin
const marginSpacing = () => {
  dataSpacing.each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'margin': $(this).attr("data-m") + p,
      'margin-top': $(this).attr("data-mt") + p,
      'margin-right': $(this).attr("data-mr") + p,
      'margin-bottom': $(this).attr("data-mb") + p,
      'margin-left': $(this).attr("data-ml") + p,
    });
  });
};marginSpacing()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body data-spacing>
  <p data-mt="20">Text</p>
  <p data-mr="20">Text</p>
  <p data-mb="20">Text</p>
  <p data-ml="20">Text</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add some HTML to the JS fiddle so we can at least debug to try to help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Devel0per95/19hnupbv/17/

Comment: Please do not put your code on external sites. StackOverflow has great snippet functionality. Always put all relevant right **in your question**.

Comment: @connexo i have updated the code and removed the external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be it:

```js
let dataAttr = "[data-m], [data-mt], [data-mr], [data-mb], [data-ml], [data-my], [data-mx], [data-p], [data-pt], [data-pr], [data-pb], [data-pl], [data-py], [data-px]";
let dataSpacing = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-spacing]' )].map(el => el.querySelectorAll(dataAttr));

dataSpacing.forEach(dataSpacingDataEls => {
  dataSpacingDataEls.forEach(el => {
    el.style.margin = el.dataset.m;
    el.style.marginTop = el.dataset.mt;
    el.style.marginRight = el.dataset.mr;
    el.style.marginBottom = el.dataset.mb;
    el.style.marginLeft = el.dataset.ml;
  })
})
```

Comment: sadly it's not returning any styling to the elements!

Comment: thanks @connexo i have fixed it by editing some of the code to meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem has been fixed thanks to "connexo's" code above.

But i have edit the code to be equivalent to my code..

Here's how my code looks like now:

```
let dataAttr = "[data-m], [data-mt], [data-mr], [data-mb], [data-ml], [data-my], [data-mx], [data-p], [data-pt], [data-pr], [data-pb], [data-pl], [data-py], [data-px]";
let dataSpacing = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-spacing]')].map(el => el.querySelectorAll(dataAttr));
let p = "px";

dataSpacing.forEach(dataSpacingDataEls => {
  dataSpacingDataEls.forEach(el => {
    el.style.margin = el.dataset.m + p;
    el.style.marginTop = el.dataset.mt + p;
    el.style.marginRight = el.dataset.mr + p;
    el.style.marginBottom = el.dataset.mb + p;
    el.style.marginLeft = el.dataset.ml + p;
  })
})
```

Credits to @connexo, thanks again :).

Comment: You don't need to do `getAttribute`. It's all in the element's `dataset`.

Comment: thanks, fixed it again turns out i just need to add the p variable that has "px" string

Comment: Also note that this will apply any of the data-properties, regardless of present, or absent, which is probably not what you want.